# How to add a file to a temporary directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-api-gateway, tempdir

I have created a temp dir using `tmpDir, err := ioutil.TempDir(dir, "OAS")`. And i used this path to add a swagger extracted from aws to this temp dir. `path = tmpDir + "/" + apiName + ".json"`, but it doesnt work. i also tried `path = <path>/OAS/apiName.json` it didn't work either. So my question is if I want add a file to this tempDir how do I define it's path?

```
cmd_3, err := exec.Command("aws", "apigateway", "get-export", "--rest-api-id", api_id, "--stage-name", stageName, "--export-type", "swagger", path).Output()
```

```
    pwd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    dir = pwd
} //gets the path where the program is executed from

    apiName := flagApiNameToGet
    stageName := flagStageName
    path = tmpDir + "/" + apiName + ".json"
    // Searching for API ID:
    for _, item := range apis.Items {
        if item.Name == apiName {
            fmt.Printf("API ID found: %+v ", item.Id)
            api_id := item.Id 
            cmd_3, err := exec.Command("aws", "apigateway", "get-export", "--rest-api-id", api_id, "--stage-name", stageName, "--export-type", "swagger", path).Output()
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            output := string(cmd_3[:])
            fmt.Println(output)
            found = true 
            break
        }
    }

func execute() {
    tmpDir, err := ioutil.TempDir(dir, "OAS")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error creating temporary directory to store OAS")
            return
        }
    fmt.Println("Temporary directory created:", tmpDir)
    defer os.RemoveAll(tmpDir)

    err = getOAS()
    if err != nil {
        utils.HandleErrorAndExit("Error getting OAS from AWS. ", err)
    }
    err = initializeProject()
    if err != nil {
        utils.HandleErrorAndExit("Error initializing project. ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Temporary directory deleted")
}
```

Comment: what does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: when i try to execute the ```aws get export command``` i get the invalid path error.

Comment: Print out the path you ended up with and see what's wrong with it. You only gave code snippets, so we can't tell.

Comment: i did print out tmpDir and it printed the path and i dnt see anything wrong with it. I'll and more of the code to the question

Comment: It's unclear from the code there are you assign `tmpDir` variable, it might be `defer os.RemoveAll(tmpDir)` or random suffix in the directory name.

Comment: actually defer os.RemoveAll(tmpDir) is like a reminder to remove the dir when its done right ? i did put it in the end of the execute function too but same error. so Even though it was before the getOAS() and initialize() functions it still didnt remove the temp directory. so I dont think thats the issue here.

Comment: the `tmpDir` variable declared in the one function and used in the other.

Comment: P.S: I declared tmpDir as a global variable.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience guys the code is pretty long so thats why i didnt add the whole code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `tmpDir` variable is global. Change your code to:

```
var err error
tmpDir, err = ioutil.TempDir(dir, "OAS")
```

Spotted the difference? `:=` and `=`. Other fuction doesnt see scope declared variable `tmpDir`.

Here is an example of your code [`playground`](https://play.golang.org/p/krIoZ3pxWjF) as you can see the global var dir is empty in other function call. [`Fixed version`](https://play.golang.org/p/wV7xO6yrgf_e)